# How do I start reading from a certain character in a string?

Tags: python

I have a list of strings that look something like this:

```
"['id', 'thing: 1\nother: 2\n']"
"['notid', 'thing: 1\nother: 2\n']"
```

I would now like to read the value of 'other' out of each of them.
I did this by counting the number at a certain position but since the position of such varies I wondererd if I could read from a certain character like a comma and say: read x_position character from comma. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that "other: " is always present in your strings, you can use it as a separator and split by it:

```
s = 'thing: 1\nother: 2'
_,number = s.split('other: ')
number
#'2'
```

(Use `int(number)` to convert the number-like string to an actual number.) If you are not sure if "other: " is present, enclose the above code in `try-except` statement.

Comment: Thanks, works but I still have number = 2\n which I need to split again but I can't get it to recognize number = number.replace("\n']", '').

Comment: `int('2\n')` is smart enough to ignore the line break, there is no need to remove it. But if you want to remove it, first remove `']'` from your statement: it is not a part of the string.